# Column invalid in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2014

I added a new column called `ip_address` to the table using the designer in SQL Server Management Studio. I then wanted to modify a stored procedure that inserts values into the table. However when I try to modify the stored procedure the program is telling me that the column name is invalid. Is there something additional that I need to do?

```
INSERT INTO FicticiousTableName (user_id, load_date, page_name, ip_address) 
VALUES (@user_id, GETDATE(), @page_name, @ip_address)
```

Comment: Show the create script for the table. Check for spelling errors. Remember [mcve]

Comment: Possibly referring to different schema or databases.  Use 3-part naming.

Comment: Are you sure you modified the table `dbo.FictitiousTableName`? Could there be another copy in a different schema? (This is why you [always use the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).) Are you sure the changes you made in the designer were actually saved by the designer? (This is why I recommend `ALTER TABLE` commands [and not designers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-the-visual-designers).)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the column names are same in the table schema
2. Check if the new added column is null-able or not
3. Check for default schema on your database. There maybe the case that you are expecting dbo.Table name to be updated, but there is another table with [defaultschema].Table exists. The procedure will refer to [defaultschema].Table as it does not specifically mentions any schema name